# Calling a function inside std::all_of

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I know that I can do that:

```
 vector<int> insidetest;

 if(std::all_of(insidetest.begin(),insidetest.end(),[](int i){return i>100;}))
    {
       std::cout << "All greater" << std::endl;
    }
```

but I want to call an other function (maybe more complex than just >1000). How can I call another function inside the std::all_of, For example:

```
   bool fun(const vector<int> *s)
   {
   return true;
   }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. The parameters passed to `std::all_of` will be of type `typename Container::value_type` (in this case, `int`), so using a function that takes a `const vector<int>* s` makes no sense.

Comment: Do you mean calling `fun` inside the lambda passed to `std::all_of`?

Comment: It's my mistake. I read that "The signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to the following: bool pred(const Type &a)", so in my case I thought it was const vector<int>*. Now I understand how it works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `fun` has such signature - there is no way.
It `fun` has signature `bool(int)` then simply write

```
if(std::all_of(insidetest.begin(),insidetest.end(),fun))
```

If you want other parameters in function - you can use `std::bind`
For example signature `bool(int, int, int)`

```
bool fun(int value, int min, int max)
{
   return value > min && value < max;
}

if(std::all_of(insidetest.begin(),insidetest.end(),
               std::bind(fun, std::placeholders::_1, 1, 5)))
```